# Installing TabView extension in a MediaWiki site

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm currently trying to install the TabView extension on my MediaWiki site. I downloaded the php file from [this page](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/TabView/TabView.php) and put it in the extensions folder as follow .../extensions/TabView/TabView.php

Added the following line to the LocalSettings.php file:

```
require_once("$IP/extensions/TabView/TabView.php");
```

Somehow, when I tried to use the  tag on of the page, I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'F' not found in /var/www/html/camnang.vysajp.org/public/extensions/TabView/TabView.php on line 107

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The [TabView extension](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/TabView/TabView.php) you linked to seems to depend on the [Wikia Nirvana framework](http://dev.wikia.com/wiki/Nirvana), and specifically on the [WikiaSuperFactory class](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/includes/wikia/nirvana/WikiaSuperFactory.class.php) (which the class "F" is a dummy subclass of).  Through the framework, it instantiates a [JSSnippets](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/JSSnippets/JSSnippets.class.php) object from the [Wikia JSSnippets extension](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/JSSnippets).

In short, the JS side of that extension seems to make use of a whole bunch of Wikia-specific code.  You could try adding all the dependencies to your wiki, but it might be easier to just replicate the functionality using standard MediaWiki features.

---

Specifically, looking at the JSSnippets class documentation (see links above), what the `addToStack()` call does is tell the browser to asynchronously load the two linked JS files and then, once the files have loaded, call the JS function `TabView.init()` with the named arguments `id` and `selected` (passed as properties of a generic object, like in JSON).

It shouldn't be too hard to do the same thing with the standard [MediaWiki ResourceLoader](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader).  First, we need to define a ResourceLoader module that loads the scripts we need (warning: untested code!):

```php
$wgResourceModules['ext.TabView'] = array(
    'scripts' => array( 'js/mustache.js', 'js/TabView.js' ),
    'localBasePath' => __DIR__,
    'remoteExtPath' => 'TabView',
);
```

Insert this somewhere near the top of the extension code, outside the function definitions.  You'll also need to copy the [mustache.js library](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/resources/wikia/libraries/mustache/mustache.js) to the `TabView/js` subdirectory.

(I *believe* loading the two JS files together like this should work, even with [ResourceLoader's scoping peculiarities](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Migration_guide_%28developers%29#Troubleshooting_and_tips).  Of course, if we had several extensions that used the mustache.js library, it would be more efficient and elegant to make it a separate module by itself, but then it would need a glue script that did something like `window.Mustache = Mustache;`.)

In the hook function, we then need to tell MediaWiki to load this module and to call the `TabView.init()` function, like this:

```php
$opts = array( 'id' => "flytabs_$id", 'selected' => $optionsIndex );
$opts = json_encode( $opts );
$js = "mw.loader.using( 'ext.TabView', function () { TabView.init($opts) } );";
$out .= "<script type='text/javascript'>$js</script>";
```

Ps. The [TabView.js file](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/TabView/js/TabView.js) says that it "[d]epends on skins/oasis/js/tab.js".  I couldn't find any file with that name in Wikia's repo, but there *is* a [skins/oasis/js/tab**s**.js](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/skins/oasis/js/tabs.js) which you *may* also need to copy into the `TabView/js` subdirectory and add to the module definition alongside mustache.js.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late reply and thank you very much for a very detailed answer. 

I just want to make sure that the below code sections are supposed to be added to the extensions/TabView/TabView.php, correct?

`$wgResourceModules['ext.TabView'] = array(
    'scripts' => array( 'js/mustache.js', 'js/tabs.js', 'js/TabView.js' ),
    'localBasePath' => __DIR__,
    'remoteExtPath' => 'TabView',
);`

Comment: And

`$opts = array( 'id' => "flytabs_$id", 'selected' => $optionsIndex );
$opts = json_encode( $opts );
$js = "mw.loader.using( 'ext.TabView', function () { TabView.init($opts) } );";
$out .= "<script type='text/javascript'>$js</script>";`

Comment: I've also added mustache.js, tabs.js and TabView.js to extenstions/TabView/js; and added 'js/tabs.js' to the ResourceLoader module but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, I dunno what's wrong, then. :( Are there any PHP or JS error messages?